# Root rights and flatpak

Tags: flatpak, permissions, sudo, root

I'm developing a docker client and I've run into the following problem: Everyone knows that docker requires root access to work properly. My application internally calls docker console commands. The question is how to get them correctly when the application is installed via flatpak?

I have 2 options without using flatpak:

1. `sudo my-app` (just run the program from the console)
2. `pkexec my-app` (more user friendly)

I don't understand how to correctly call docker console commands when the application is installed via flatpak. The commands return a permissions error when using flatpak-spawn.

I hope to help, thanks